# INSERT/INNER JOIN MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I am attempting to insert into the table 'refunds' but I need to reference another table 'transactions' date created. Both tables share the transactionId value. I want to insert into the 'refunds' table if the date created is < 48 hours old. So far I have this insert statement, but cannot get it to work with any sort of join.

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO refunds
SET 
transactionId = ?,
refundAmount = ?
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do an `INSERT/SELECT`, something like:

```sql
INSERT INTO refunds(transactionId, <col2>, ...)
SELECT transactionId, <col2>, ...
FROM transactions
WHERE date_col > DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 2 DAY)
```

This will let you `INSERT` your `refund` table based on rows from the `transactions` table.

Comment: if I took this approach, how would I assign specific values to the columns in the refunds table?

Comment: What values do you want to assign?  If you want them to come from another table, you can incorporate that into your query as a join.  If they are just literal values, just add them as a string into the `SELECT` line.  Just construct the `SELECT` part of the query as you want to see the rows `INSERT`ed into your target table.